# Python - How to convert utf literal such as '\xc3\xb6' to the letter ö

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, urllib

I am trying to convert an encoded url with german Umlaute into a string with those Umlaute.

Here is an example of an encoded string = 'K%C3%B6nnen'.
I would like to convert it to 'Können'

When I use urllib.unquote(a) I get this returned: 'K\xc3\xb6nnen'

\xc3\xb6 I found out is a utf literal.

How can I convert this to an ö ? I find that if I use the print function it converts it correctly, but I cannot figure out how to get a function to return this value? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

With decode("utf-8")

```
print('K\xc3\xb6nnen'.decode("utf-8"))
```

OUTPUT

```
Können
```

EXTRA edit, take care with that

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.append(s.decode("utf-8")) #s is the string
>>> l
[u'K\xf6nnen']
>>> print(l)
[u'K\xf6nnen']
>>> print(l[0])
Können
>>>
```

Python will use codification to manage string, print can give you the representation but no the real value, use repr(s) for real value