# String object has no attribute 'decode' when converting UTF-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to convert `G\xc3\xb6del` to `Gödel` (specifically, `\xc3\xb6d` to `ö`), but I can't find a method for going about doing this. When I run the below code, I receive an error:

```py
>>> string = '\xc3\xb6'
>>> string.decode(encoding='UTF-8') 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56081392/python-how-to-convert-utf-literal-such-as-xc3-xb6-to-the-letter-%C3%B6) didn't seem to help, nor did any others that seemed similar, as they were all from `2.x`. A friend mentioned base 64 encoding, but I'm not sure in what way that helps. I can't seem to find what I'm supposed to do to convert it in `3.8`, so what would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: How do you end up with that string? Could it be a byte object at some point?
`b'G\xc3\xb6del'.decode('utf-8')` --> `'Gödel'`

Comment: @UlasKeles it was indeed a byte object. I extracted it from a webpage, the SCP foundation to be exact, and wanted to send it in a message with my Discord bot. I have found a solution to the issue, and I will be posting the answer to it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that a string is already decoded. Basically you `encode` a string object to a byte object, and the inverse operation is `decoding` a byte object to a string object. That's why a string has no attribute `decode`. Think of it like this:

```
String -> encode -> Byte
Byte -> decode -> String
```

In this case, the solution would be to call the encode method and pass in `'utf8'` or `'ascii'`, depending on the context and situation.

*However,* it isn't just converting it to a string object that is the case here. As the OA of this question, I do know exactly what this was meant for, and how I came to a solution. The value `Gödel` was gained by scraping an SCP Foundation page, finding the Object Class to then pass onto my Discord bot for a command. Here was my code:

```py
link = f"http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-{num}"
page = get(link)

obj_class = [str(i) for i in page.iter_lines() if b"Object Class:" in i][0]
# ^ There should only be one line in the document matching that requirement.
# The type of this line is a byte object, which is why conversion is necessary later on.
obj_class = re.findall('(?<=\<\/strong> )(.*?)(?=\<)', obj_class)[0]
# ^ Find the actual class in that line.
print(obj_class)  # expected Gödel, got G\xc3\xb6del instead.
```

The above would not raise an exception, it just simply wouldn't convert the character encoding as desired. My fix was simple, once I understood what was going on; replace the `str(i)` for `i.decode('utf8')`.

```py
obj_class = [i.decode('utf8') for i in page.iter_lines() if b"Object Class:" in i][0]
# ^ decoding it there really makes the difference, converting it to utf-8 without dealing with
# the issues of decoded strings later on.
```

This would now return the desired value, `Gödel`, rather than `G\xc3\xb6del`. I hope that this helps. Please let me know if I've made any mistakes, so I can make any necessary corrections.